# Making a button in the form have a different method for sending the data to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html form and 2 buttons in it. The method of the form is post. However, I want to be able to send an **get** ajax request by clicking on the second button. But it sends a **post** request even though I set `$.ajax({type: "GET"})`.

I can't place the second button outside of the form because the layout won't look as I want: the second button will be placed on the next line.

So the bottom line is that I want the second button to be on the same line as the first one and to send a get ajax request.

How can I do that? I think that to rewrite post form method get would be easily.

Comment: Can we see the relevant HTML and the code for making the AJAX call, please?

Comment: what kind of button is the second one? `type="submit"` or `type="button"`? A code snippet would be fine

Comment: it cant be type=submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the default post action assigned to the button before making the ajax request,

```
$("#button").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
        .....
        .....
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The general principle is that you want to prevent the default action of that second button, and simply make your AJAX call inside the event handler. The code would look roughly like this:

```
$('selector-for-your-button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // nullifies the click, form won't be submitted
    // make your AJAX call here
});
```